# Why is my character randomly looking up?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I was playing Fortnite and randomly my character starts to look up even though I didn’t press the joystick to look up and it did it on its own. Can someone help and find a way to stop this bug?

Comment: You might want to investigate whether your controller is at fault. Sometimes joysticks drift just slightly off-center.

Comment: Also try to restart your controller then your console. This happened to me and restarting my controller help most times.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely caused by an issue with your controller. You controller may be damaged - even if the damage isn't visible - in a way which causes the joysticks to force your character to aim upwards.

Possible solutions would be to restart your controller. restarting your console, providing new batteries, or [percussive maintenance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/percussive_maintenance), or purchasing a new controller.